# Jquery Not Operator not working

Tags: jquery, html

The below is the code snippet where in I want to select the div tag completely but not the  tag inside it. The Jquery code is not working for it.

```
$(".accordion:not(#temp)").click(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        //do something
    });

});
```

This is the html snippet

```
<div class="connectivity_details accordion" id="connect1">
  <span id="connectivity_details_heading">Connectivity Details</span>
  <div id="temp">
    <a id="connectivity1" class="another_connectivity" href="#">Add another connectivity type</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the whole div "connect1" but not the div "temp" or  tag "connectivity1"
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$(".accordion:not(#temp)")` - this would select the div with class `accordion`, and not it's children

Comment: Also if you want to select all the children without `#temp` as in this example it turns out you only want to select the span `#connectivity_details_heading` why not just target that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there are two issues in your actual code:

- You are targeting elements with class `accordion` which don't
  have `id="temp"`, you aren't targeting its children.
- And you don't need to use `$(this).each` to access these children,
  you can simply use `$(this)` to directly access the current element, there's no need to use a `.each()` loop here.

Here's how should be your code to target children that doesn't have `id="temp"`:

```
$(".accordion *").not("#temp").click(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

**This is a working snippet:**

```js
$(".accordion *").not("#temp").click(function(){
        console.log(this);
});
```

```css
#temp{
  width:300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:orange;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="connectivity_details accordion" id="connect1">
<span id="connectivity_details_heading">Connectivity Details</span>
<div id="temp"><a id="connectivity1" class="another_connectivity" href="#">Add another connectivity type</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in this way, it should work. try this working example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="connectivity_details accordion" id="connect1">
 <span id="connectivity_details_heading">Connectivity Details</span>
 <div id="temp" class="stack"><a id="connectivity" class="another_connectivity" href="#">Add another connectivity type</a> </div>
 <div id="temp1" class="stack"><a id="connectivity1" class="another_connectivity" href="#">Add another connectivity type temp 1</a> </div>
 <div id="temp2" class="stack"><a id="connectivity2" class="another_connectivity" href="#">Add another connectivity type temp 2</a> </div>
</div>
 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".stack").not('[id="temp"]').click(function(){
 alert("i am not the temp, i'm another");
});



</script>
</html>
```